# MySQL tuning in memory excess case

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL server with 500mb database running on a server with 8Gb of RAM. Are there any sensible tunings which will take all available memory (I mean about 80% of 8Gb)?

Comment: MySQL comes with a number of sample configurations, I'm sure you can find one which works well in a large memory environment...

Comment: Updated my answer with actual formula !!!

Comment: Updated my answer with formulas for both InnoDB and MyISAM.

Comment: Question : Is your DB part of a high trafficked website ???

Comment: Update my answer to tune max_connections

Comment: BTW you can set innodb_buffer_pool_size to 1536M (that's 1.5G)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you are tuning for. If you want to tune for InnoDB and or MyISAM, even in a low memory envitronment, you will need to scale formulas from this link --> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-are-the-main-differences-between-innodb-and-myisam/2194#2194

Basically, you want 75% of RAM dedicated for InnoDB. If all MyISAM, measured recommendation from the formulas given in the link.

UPDATE 2011-07-21 13:52 EDT

Cut and Paste this Formula

**SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(KBS/POWER(1024,IF(PowerOfTwo<0,0,IF(PowerOfTwo>3,0,PowerOfTwo)))+0.49999),
SUBSTR(' KMG',IF(PowerOfTwo<0,0,IF(PowerOfTwo>3,0,PowerOfTwo))+1,1)) recommended_innodb_buffer_pool_size

FROM (SELECT SUM(data_length+index_length) KBS FROM information_schema.tablesM

WHERE engine='InnoDB') A,

(SELECT 2 PowerOfTwo) B;**

It will output the InnoDB Buffer Pool Size for your given dataset.

Cut and Paste This One as Well

**SELECT CONCAT(ROUND(KBS/POWER(1024,IF(PowerOfTwo<0,0,IF(PowerOfTwo>3,0,PowerOfTwo)))+0.4999),
SUBSTR(' KMG',IF(PowerOfTwo<0,0,IF(PowerOfTwo>3,0,PowerOfTwo))+1,1)) recommended_key_buffer_size

FROM (SELECT LEAST(POWER(2,32),KBS1) KBS FROM

(SELECT SUM(index_length) KBS1 FROM information_schema.tables

WHERE engine='MyISAM' AND table_schema NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql')) AA

) A,(SELECT 2 PowerOfTwo) B;**

It will output the MyISAM Key Buffer Size for your given dataset.

Please run both of these formulas. Keep in mind that MyISAM only caches index pages. InnoDB needs both data nad index pages cached. Probably the combined sizes of them both will be less than 500 MB.

UPDATE 2011-07-21 14:54 EDT

You may also want to tune per-DB Connection Settings

[I recommend tuning your max_connections](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/1229/877)

You may also want to download mysqltuner.pl and run it on the DB server.

```
wget mysqltuner.pl
```

This perl script will tell if you have overconfigured for DB Connections or not as well the maximum RAM mysql expects to have. If the the percetage of installed RAM needed exceeds 80%, lower the per_connect DB settings (sort_buffer_size, read_buffer_size, join_buffer_size and so forth)

Comment: So it is reasonable to use only data_size+index_size for innodb. It is 1.3Gb for my server. How should I spend other free memory? May be query_cache?

Comment: Your note about max_connections looks very reasonable, thank you!